# I'm trying to recreate this plot in R, but I can't figure out how to add a legend label for the median (red triangle)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHJkS.jpg)

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13),          #patient ID
                     t1 = c(37, 66, 28, 60, 44, 24, 47, 44, 33, 47),    #evaluation before
                     t4 = c(33, 45, 27, 39, 24, 29, 24, 37, 27, 42),    #evaluation after
                     sexe = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1))      

pval <- wilcox.test(x = mydata$t1,y = mydata$t4, paired = T,exact = F)$p.value %>% round(2)

df <- mydata %>% 
  pivot_longer(2:3,names_to = "Time") %>% # Pivot into long-format
  mutate(sexe = as.factor(sexe),
         Time = as.factor(Time)) # Make factors 

ggplot(df,aes(Time,value,color = sexe,group = ID)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  stat_summary(inherit.aes = F,aes(Time,value),
    geom = "point", fun = "median", col = "red", 
    size = 3, shape = 24,fill = "red"
  ) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.7, y = 60, label = paste('P-Value is',pval)) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.4,1.6)) +
  theme_bw()
```

I was able to modify the plot for my data and my labels but I just can't figure out how to add an additional label above the existing "sexe" legend, with the triangle for the median

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something in the legend, it has to go inside `aes`:

```r
ggplot(df,aes(Time,value,color = sexe,group = ID)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  stat_summary(inherit.aes = F, aes(Time, value, shape = 'Median'),
               geom = "point", fun = "median", col = "red", 
               size = 3 ,fill = "red"
  ) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.7, y = 60, label = paste('P-Value is',pval)) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.4,1.6)) +
  scale_shape_manual(NULL, values = 24) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]